# download cert with curl, echo cert value into openssl

Tags: bash, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to get an intermediate certificate using `curl`, and process the certificate without writing it to a file.

I've figured out how to process a leaf cert and get the distribution point, but that's where I'm stuck.

For an example, let's take stackoverflow (seems pertinent). The first intermediate cert for SO is from `http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt`.

In an interactive shell, I can do something like this to store the value of the certificate into a variable:

> DigiCertIntermediateCert=$(curl http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt)

Then I can check the value of the cert by doing something like this:

> echo "$DigiCertIntermediateCert" | openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM

This outputs the nice and friendly PEM-formed cert. It looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEsTCCA5mgAwIBAgIQBOHnpNxc8vNtwCtCuF0VnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBs
...
cPUeybQ=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(Note: this will change when the intermediate cert changes, if this isn't exactly the value you're seeing, don't freak out)

Neat! Seems like this should work. Let's throw all this logic into a script with some basic case handling (like if the cert is in a different form, then we should interpret it as that form) and we should be done, right?

```
#! /bin/bash

cert_content=$(curl -s "$1")
echo "$cert_content"

if echo "$cert_content" | openssl x509 -text -noout; then
    echo "Not converting"
    echo "$cert_content"
else
    echo "Converting"
    echo "$cert_content" | openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM
fi
```

What does this output when we feed the url?

```
...
[binary contents of a certificate]
...
unable to load certificate
4667577964:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.230.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:683:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
Converting
unable to load certificate
4421875308:error:0DFFF08E:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:not enough data:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.230.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.c:251:
```

So it's pretty easy to see that the certificate is in DER form (because of the "Converting" line), but it looks like the certificate is not complete - note the error:

```
unable to load certificate
4421875308:error:0DFFF08E:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:not enough data:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.230.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.c:251:
```

says that there is not enough data.

Why is this different between the script and the actions I'm taking in the shell? How can I feed the binary cert through the openssl tool to get the PEM-form cert out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question alludes, I was not strict enough in my shell usage. The "interactive" session was done using `zsh`, and the script was run under `bash`. `zsh` will append an `EOF` to variables passed through its pipes, while `bash` (apparently) does not. Now my quest becomes how to append an EOF to a variable in bash (which, apparently, is non-trivial).

Comment: There's no such thing as EOF 'in' a variable; end of data is implicit, even though you may signal EOF _on terminal/console input_ with a character. The problem is that bash can't handle **null bytes** in a variable (and zsh can), and a DER cert contains quite a few null bytes. Note for real programs (not `echo`) _no_ shell can pass null byte(s) in an argument; the Unix API prevents it. The safe way is to store text-friendly PEM in the first place: `cert=$(curl -s ... | openssl x509 -inform der)`

Comment: PS: you do know you can get the intermediate cert(s) _from any conforming SSL/TLS server_ with `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port [-servername $host if it uses SNI and OpenSSL < 1.1.1] -showcerts` already in PEM?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the responses - my questions was less about getting leaf certs and more about getting intermediates. For example, last I checked, the intermediate cert for SO was at http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt - how would I get that file, read it into a variable, and then pass that to another part of the script _was_ an open question, but your first comment helped solve it. Thanks!